# DoesNotExist error in django view/template with one-to-one field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have these models.

```
class Storypak(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField('Headline', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True)

class Story(models.Model):
    storypak = models.OneToOneField('Storypak', blank=True, null=True)
    copy = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

And this view.

```
def pak_detail(request, pak_id, year, month, day):
    pak = Storypak.objects.get(pk=pak_id)
    t = loader.get_template('storypak_detail.html')
    c = Context ({
        'pak' : pak,
        })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

When I try to use an `if` statement in my template, a `DoesNotExist` error is thrown.  The documentation I can find indicates that these errors should be silenced.  Shouldn't `if pak.story` resolve `False` and not throw an error?  What am I missing?  I think it may have something to do with the OneToOne relationship, but I can't find anything in the docs dealing with this specifically.

Here is the relevant template code as I remember it.  I don't have the file on this computer.  I'll fix it later if it isn't correct and possibly post the debug info if that would help.

```
{% if pak.story %}
    <p>{{ pak.story.copy }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: please show the template at least the part that causes the error

Comment: updated with template snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a related bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10227

here is the source for the `if` tag: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py#L267

as you see, the tag's `render` method does not catch anything but `VariableDoesNotExist`.

Comment: I don't really understand gsakkis' explanation, but I should be able to implement the solution.  Thanks.

Comment: just check pak.story in your view, where you will be able to catch the exception, not in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough detail to troubleshoot much past the error here, but the simple error message can only be triggered by one statement in your view, that is...

```
pak = Storypak.objects.get(pk=pak_id)
```

The pak_id is either invalid, or your model is malformed and a Storypak with that id doesn't exist. That is the only call to an object that would raise a DoesNotExist error. You can verify it is a valid id by adding `raise Exception(str(pak_id))` before this line to see what it is attempting to "get." Verify that record exists in the storypak table.

Comment: The pak item is good.  I'm able to display other attributes like headline, etc.  When the pak has a related "story" item, it renders fine.  When there is no story item, a DoesNotExist exception is raised.  That's what is confusing me because I thought these exceptions were silenced by default.  I want to create a template that renders differently based on the contents of the pak.  Maybe this is the wrong approach.